# "If someone would answer my question" vs. "If someone answered my question"

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, modality

> (a) I'd appreciate it if someone **would answer** my question.
>
> (b) I'd appreciate it if someone **answered** my question.

Which sentence is grammatically OK? I hesitate because I am not able to decide whether this clause is conditional or not.

P. S. Is it necessary to use "it" there?

Answer (score 1):

As a native US English speaker, either sentence sounds correct to me; the first may perhaps be a little softer or polite.

I think you definitely need the "it."